# Python Convert TPL/MTPL format to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below mtpl file:

```
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_CLO
{
    MeasurementTypes = "Voltage";
    Pins = "Adidas";
}
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN
{
    LowLimits = "90.05V";
    MeasurementTypes = "Voltage";
    Pins = "Nike";
}
```

I Wish to used python to convert to pandas dataframe:

Expected Output:

```
Name                              Type                Value
---------------------------------------------------------------
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_CLO    MeasurementTypes    Voltage
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_CLO    Pins                Adidas
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN   LowLimits           90.05V
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN   MeasurementTypes    Voltage
Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN   Pins                Nike
```

Anyone can share me ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with [re](/questions/tagged/re) :

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open("input.mtpl") as f:
    mtpl = f.read()

pat = r'^([\w\s]+)\n\{\n((?:.*;\n)+)\}'

matches = re.findall(pat, mtpl, re.MULTILINE)

data = [{"Name": f"{m[0]}",
         "Type": vals.split(" = ")[0].strip(),
         "Value": vals.split(" = ")[1].strip(";\"")}
        for m in matches for vals in m[1].strip().split("\n")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

​Output:

```
print(df)
                              Name              Type    Value
0   Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_CLO  MeasurementTypes  Voltage
1   Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_CLO              Pins   Adidas
2  Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN         LowLimits   90.05V
3  Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN  MeasurementTypes  Voltage
4  Test PrimeDcTestMethod SOC_OPEN              Pins     Nike
```